# reduce the number of IF statements in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have written a function that is going to have up to 72 IF statements
and i was hoping to write code that will be much shorter,  but have no idea where to start

The function reads the self.timeselect variable when a radio button is selected and the result is saved to a text file called missing_time.txt. If the result is equal to 1 then save "0000" to the file, if the result is 2 save then 0020 to the text file etc. This can be for 72 possible combinations.

Is there a smarter way to simplify the function ?

```
def buttonaction():
    selectedchoice = ""            
    if self.timeselect.get() == 1:                
        selectedchoice = "0000"
        orig_stdout = sys.stdout
        f = open('missing_time.txt', 'w')
        sys.stdout = f
        print(selectedchoice)
        f.close()
    if self.timeselect.get() == 2:                
        selectedchoice = "0020"
        orig_stdout = sys.stdout
        f = open('missing_time.txt', 'w')
        sys.stdout = f
        print(selectedchoice)
        f.close()

self.timeselect = tkinter.IntVar()

self.Radio_1 = tkinter.Radiobutton(text="0000",variable = 
self.timeselect,indicator = 0 ,value=1)  
self.Radio_1.place(x=50,y=200)
self.Radio_2 = tkinter.Radiobutton(text="0020",variable = 
self.timeselect,indicator = 0 ,value=2)  
self.Radio_2.place(x=90,y=200)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
choice_map = {
    1 : "0000",
    2 : "0020"
}

def buttonaction():
    selected = self.timeselect.get()        
    if 0 < selected < 73:  # This works as intended in Python
        selectedchoice = choice_map[selected]
        # Do you intend to append to file instead of replacing it? 
        # See text below.
        with open("missing_time.txt", 'w') as outfile:
            outfile.write(selectedchoice + "\n")
            print(selectedchoice)
```

Better yet, if there is a pattern that relates the value of `self.timeselect.get()` to the string that you write out, generate `selectchoice` directly from that pattern instead of using a dictionary to do the mapping.

### Edit

I find it a bit odd that you are clearing the file "missing_time.txt" every time you call `buttonaction`. If your intention is to append to it, change the file mode accordingly.

Also, instead of opening and closing the file each time, you might just want to open it once and pass the handler to buttonaction or keep it as a global depending on how you use it.

Finally, if you do not intend to catch the KeyError from an invalid key, you can do what @Clifford suggests and use `choice_map.get(selected, "some default value that does not have to be str")`.

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do in this case is construct a string from the integer value `self.timeselect.get()`.

```
selectedchoice = self.timeselect.get()
if 0 < selectedchoice < 73:
    orig_stdout = sys.stdout
    f = open('missing_time.txt', 'w')
    sys.stdout = f
    print( str(selectedchoice).zfill(4) )     # Convert choice to 
                                              # string with leading
                                              # zeros to 4 charaters
    f.close()
```

Further in the interests of simplification, redirecting stdout and restoring it is a cumbersome method of outputting to a file.  Instead, you can write directly to the file:

```
    with open('missing_time.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(selectedchoice + "\n")
```

Note that because we use the `with` context manager here, `f` is automatically closed when we leave this context so there is no need to call `f.close()`. Ultimately you end up with:

```
selectedchoice = self.timeselect.get()
if 0 < selectedchoice < 73:
    with open('missing_time.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write( str(selectedchoice).zfill(4) + "\n" )
```

Even if you did use the conditionals each one differs only in the first line, so only that part need be conditional and the remainder of the content performed after the conditionals.  Moreover all conditionals are mutually exclusive so you can use `else-if`:

```
    if self.timeselect.get() == 1:                
        selectedchoice = "0000"

    elif self.timeselect.get() == 2:                
        selectedchoice = "0020"

    ...

    if 0 < selectedchoice < 73:
        with open('missing_time.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(selectedchoice + "\n")
```

In circumstances where there is no direct arithmetic relationship between `selectchoice` and the required string, or the available choices are perhaps not contiguous, it is possible to implement a `switch` using a dictionary:

```
choiceToString = {
    1:  "0001",
    2:  "0002",
    ...
    72: "0072",
}

selectedchoice = choiceToString.get( self.timeselect.get(), "Invalid Choice")

if selectedchoice != "Invalid Choice":
    with open('missing_time.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(selectedchoice + "\n")
```

Comment: Very detailed explanation on the reason for the changes. +1. Just a few minor comments. We can write out to file directly using the file object `f` using `f.write(selectedchoice + "\n")` and Python allows the condition to be expressed as `0 < selectedchoice < 73`. But overall an in depth exposition of the thought process behind the refactor.

Comment: @lightalchemist : As you can see I am not a Python programmer; just a programmer!  (C++ on embedded systems primarily).  I'd apply your suggestions, but am hardly qualified to do so.  I answered most of this by googling Python syntax!  Feel free to edit for me.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no switch statement in Python, you can't really reduce the number of if statements. But I see 2 two way to optimize and reduce your code length.

First, you can use some

```
if condition:

elif condition:
```

instead of

```
if condition:

if condition:
```

since you can't have self.timeselect.get() evaluated to more than one int.
Secondly you can wrap all the code that doesn't vary in a function.
You can get rid of selectedchoice and put

```
orig_stdout = sys.stdout
f = open('missing_time.txt', 'w')
sys.stdout = f
print(selectedchoice)
f.close()
```

in a function writeToFile(selectedOption)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the values are arbitrary and there's no defined pattern. I also see that the only thing that changes in your code is the selectedChoice variable. You can use a [Dictionary](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp) in such cases. A dictionary's elements are key/value pairs so you can reference the key and get the value.

```
dictionary = {
    1:"0000",
    2:"0020",
    3:"0300",
    4:"4000"
}

def buttonAction():
    selectedChoice = dictionary[self.timeselect.get()]
    if 0<selectedChoice<=72:
        f=open('missing_time.txt','w')
        f.write(selectedChoice+" ")
        f.close()
        print(choice)
```